# Problems while getting the content of the page with curl

Tags: curl

guys.

I'm a bit stuck with the current situation i get.
I need to check the presence of the link in the partner's site, For this i'm trying to get page content with the following command:

```
"curl -A 'Mozilla\/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; hu; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko\/20101026 Firefox\/3.6.12' -L --retry 2 -s -m 30 --connect-timeout 10 -b \/tmp\/cookie_file.txt -c \/tmp\/cookie_file.txt 'www.partnersite.com\/
```

The thing is that it's working weird: one time it returns the content of the page, then another time it get the blank one.
So i checked the responce of the server and found out that one time the response is :HTTP/1.0 200 OK  then it gets the empty page, then another time the response is "HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved" and then it gets the content.
How it's possible? Do you have any ides what is wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the blank content response you are referring to the one where the HTTP response code is 302? or is the page that this redirect is sending you blank?

Comment: I get the blank page when HTTP/1.0 200 OK. When it's redirecting - it works fine

Comment: If that is the case, then it may be that something is screwy on the network between you and your partner site, possibly even a misconfiguration of their web server? You tend *not* to get HTTP 200 OK responses when everything is fine!

Comment: My last sentence came out wrongly! I meant that when something is behaving in the way you have said, you tend not to get perfectly valid but blank 200 OK responses from the server without reason, and generally the reason is something wrong on the server or cache side of things.

Answer (score 0):

dear instead using cURL use 'simple_html_dom' class which is very easy to implement and u can find documentation too. I used it for long and its very simple. any other problem related to simple_html_dom contact me.